# How do I rotate a GLKView around the x-axis ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I have subclassed a GLKView and I would like to rotate it around the x-axis. I have tried to apply the method in raywenderlich's tutorial, with no results. The difference is, that I have a GLKView and he happens to do everything with a GLKViewController(+ its delegate). So I do not have the update method of the delegate etc. etc. I have had almost no experience with OpenGL (just starting out), so I hope I encounter some enlightenment here.

**ViewController.m**

```
    EAGLContext * context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2]; 
    BlogCell *view = [[BlogCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 80) context:context]; 
    view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
    view.context = context; 
    view.delegate = view; 
    [view setupGL];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

**MyGLKViewSubclass.m**

```
- (void)setupGL {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);


    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];

    NSError * error;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];
    GLKTextureInfo * info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
    if (info == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 
                          3,         
                          GL_FLOAT,   
                          GL_FALSE,    
                          sizeof(Vertex),   
                          (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position) 
                          );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));


    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;

}




- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.contentScaleFactor = 2.0;
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


}
```

**This is where I would like to rotate my object**

```
 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint lastLoc = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(lastLoc.x - location.x, lastLoc.y - location.y);

    float rotX = -1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(diff.y / 2.0);
    float rotY = -1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(diff.x / 2.0);

    GLKVector3 xAxis = GLKVector3Make(1, 0, 0);
    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(rotMatrix, rotX, xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z);
    GLKVector3 yAxis = GLKVector3Make(0, 1, 0);
    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(rotMatrix, rotY, yAxis.x, yAxis.y, yAxis.z);
    [self update];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to have anything to run your draw loop. Put this in your viewDidLoad:

```
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render:)];
displayLink.frameInterval = 2;
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Define displayLink as a property in your header and change the @selector(render:) to your rendering function (doesnt have to be that glkview one since you arent using a GLKViewController).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code,unfortunately to no avail. What works for me is using `[self display]` whenever I need my GLKView to be redrawn. By the way I set the delegate to the GLKView itself, so its delegate method will be called when I call the `display` method on it. Is that a bad approach ?

Comment: The displayLink run loop is the same run loop as that provided by the GLKViewController/GLKView combination. With CADisplayLink, you have a granular view of the number of cycles that transpired since the last refresh; but, that information is irrelevant to everyone I know. With GLKViewController, I can set the number of frames per second for a given video; videos that play back at 15 fps don't need to be rendered at 60 fps. Being able to reduce the fps makes for a snappier app than without.

Answer (score 0):

There are four requirements for rotating a GLKView:
1. Rotation-related code must be placed inside the view controller
2. 90° must be added to the rotation for landscape orientation
3. Rotation-related code must be enclosed in a UIView animation block
4. The degrees should be expressed in radians, and as a negative number

Here's the code I used, successfully:

**In the GLKViewController implementation file (.m):**

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) { return degrees * M_PI/180; }
```

.
.
.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) || (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
        ((PlayerView *)self.view).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(-90.0));
        ((PlayerView *)self.view).frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
} else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) || (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
        ((PlayerView *)self.view).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(-180.0));
        ((PlayerView *)self.view).frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"--------------------------- orientation could not be determined");
}
```

These requirements may sound a little suspect; but, I guarantee you that you will not rotate it any other way, and maintain consistency at all orientations and all aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than rotating the view is rotating the quad texture coordinates; although it is not demonstrated in any of Apple's sample code or documentation, their documentation does recommend rotating the output over rotating the GLKView.

Here are all the permutations for quad texture coordinate settings:

```
static const GLfloat noRotationTextureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat rotateLeftTextureCoordinates[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat rotateRightTextureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
};

static const GLfloat verticalFlipTextureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};

static const GLfloat horizontalFlipTextureCoordinates[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat rotateRightVerticalFlipTextureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat rotateRightHorizontalFlipTextureCoordinates[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
};

static const GLfloat rotate180TextureCoordinates[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

To use this within the GLKView used in their AVBasicVideo... sample app, for example:

1. Use `self.bounds.size` instead of the `self.presentationRect.size` so that your output fills the entire screen regardless of its rotation:

   ```
   CGRect vertexSamplingRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.bounds.size, self.eaglLayer.bounds);
   ```
2. For a value of 1.0, use max; for 0.0, use min;

   GLfloat quadTextureData[] =
       {
           CGRectGetMaxX(textureSamplingRect), CGRectGetMinY(textureSamplingRect),
           CGRectGetMaxX(textureSamplingRect), CGRectGetMaxY(textureSamplingRect),
           CGRectGetMinX(textureSamplingRect), CGRectGetMinY(textureSamplingRect),
           CGRectGetMinX(textureSamplingRect), CGRectGetMaxY(textureSamplingRect)
       };